# Matlab - Temperature data from 18 thermocouples, each with xyz coordinates, sampled at 1Hz. How could I make an animated 3D surface plot?

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab

I've measured the temperature evolution in a box at 18 locations using thermocouples. I have 18 columns of temperature data in excel, each row being a time step of 1 second (sampling at 1Hz). Each thermocouple has a xyz coordinate.

How could I make an animated 3D surface plot showing the evolution of the temperature in the box on Matlab?